# Как создать таблицу с нужным именем фалйа в FoxPro? (На sql)

Tags: sql, база-данных

Должна создаваться **таблица с именем** realizations. В качестве **имени Файла** должна быть тещая дата ( **значение** текущей даты получу через Visual Studio c# ). Как сохранить файл таблицы с нужным мне именем если таблица в базе должна называться realizations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сначала создать таблтцу под нужным именем. Файл будет иметь имя, такое же, как у таблицы которую вы создаете

```
Create Table 12092016 (record_code int(5), item_name char(50), price numeric(9), items_number int(5), money_amount int (12), record_date date)
```

После этого можно переименовать таблицу и установить нужное вам имя таблицы в базе. Файл таблицы базы данных будет иметь прежнее название, но в схеме данных данных имя таблицы измениться.

```
RENAME TABLE 12092016 TO tabletable
```

Answer (score 1):

Таблицы бывают свободные и входящие в базу данных. Для таблиц, входящих в базу данных, вы можете задать два имени. Одно вводится в диалоговом окне Create (Создать), а второе — на вкладке Table(Таблица) окна конструктора таблицы. Имя, вводимое в диалоговом окне Create (Создать) при создании таблицы, является именем файла, в котором таблица сохраняется на диске.

Comment: Мне нужно сделать это через запрос